# Android KitKat 4.4 Hangouts cannot handle Sending SMS intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-hangouts, android-4.4-kitkat

Code for sending sms that worked perfectly until Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean) and stopped working since 4.4 (KitKat)

I'm just preparing the text message for the user, but they need to choose the number to send to.

The code I have used is:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);

    activity.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Since it stopped working, I have also tried the `ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_SENDTO` Neither worked, I also tried the `sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");`, but again nothing worked.

I looked at several answers on Stack Overflow [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560323/send-sms-message-using-non-default-sms-app-on-android-4-4) and [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979754/android-sms-intent-hangouts-2-0), but both answers aren't dealing with the requirements I have.

What I would like to do:

- Send sms with sms app only, not by all apps that serves the send intent
- Prepare the text for the user
- Let the user choose the phone number to send the message to

For moderators:
It is not a duplicate questions, since the questions, doesn't ask the exact same thing, the need here is to send sms with no phone number, and none of the questions and answers dealt with that.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I attached a code that solve the problem by doing the following:

- Check the OS version
- In case that older version (prior to KitKat), use the old method
- If new API, check the default sms package. if there is any, set it as the package, otherwise, let the user choose the sharing app.

Here is the code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) //At least KitKat
    {
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(activity); //Need to change the build to API 19

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, smsText);

        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null)//Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose any app that support this intent.
        {
            sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
        activity.startActivity(sendIntent);

    }
    else //For early versions, do what worked for you before.
    {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);
        activity.startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Having the same issue as the user above. Will try this today! :)

Comment: Is there a way to also tell the default sms app to which contact we want to send the message? (as was possible using adding "smsto:[phone number] to the uri)

Comment: @dors I didn't test it, but I would check the ACTION_SENDTO. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853220/android4-4-can-not-handle-sms-intent-with-vnd-android-dir-mms-sms?lq=1 is talking about the same topic, you might just need to add the setPackage call.

Comment: @dors you can use 
Intent sendIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse (uri));

Comment: Thanks guys! And I will add one more challenge: is it still possible to pass predefined text to show in the sms message?

Comment: @dors again, I didn't test sending sms with predefined text and number, but I would try the  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, smsText) from this answer. I hope it will work, and it would be great if you could write here if it succeeded or not for other people. Good luck

Comment: @dors Adding the EXTRA_TEXT property does work on KitKat, with Hangouts at least.

Comment: Using `text/plain` MIME-type doesn't work on Lollipop. Moreover, Hangouts ignores `sms_body` and `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` on Lollipop and I didn't manage to find a way to make it work.

Comment: @Michael While you need only text body without pre-defined phone number, the code in this answer does work in Lollipop with Hangouts. It doesn't work if you try to add phone number. This is a bug in Hangouts, and currently we couldn't find a solution for the situation when you need both phone number and sms body. The answer above talks about sms body only. If you find a solution, please write it here that other people could use it as well. Happy new year

Comment: @nheimann1 Yep, I need both body and recipients. And setting `text/plain` as the MIME-type leads to `ActivityNotFoundException`, at least when using `smsto` URI scheme.

Comment: How to combine this with Whatsapp / Hangouts (chat instead of sms) via phonenumber?

Comment: Can I send image using this code? I have tried for image attachment using the following line, but it's not working for me. i.e.smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);

Answer (score 19):

This one should work on all android versions and all sms apps (including Hangouts).

```
public static boolean sendSms(Context context, String text, String number) {
    return sendSms(context, text, Collections.singletonList(number));
}

public static boolean sendSms(Context context, String text, List<String> numbers) {

    String numbersStr = TextUtils.join(",", numbers);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("sms:" + numbersStr);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
    intent.putExtra("address", numbersStr);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
        if(defaultSmsPackageName != null) {
            intent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
    } else {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    }

    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can I send image using this code? I have tried for image attachment using the following line, but it's not working for me. i.e.smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);

Comment: If you can explain how to make intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment); work, that'd be great :)

Answer (score 17):

Combining the proposed solutions, the following provides presetting the recipient **and** the text.

```
Intent intent;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) // Android 4.4 and up
{
    String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(activity);

    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(toContact.toString())));
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);

    if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) // Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose any app that supports this intent.
    {
        intent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
    }
}
else
{
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    intent.putExtra("address", toContact.toString());
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
}
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

The only problem remaining is that you end up in Hangouts (Nexus 5), and you might have to press "back" multiple times to effectively cancel the SMS.

Comment: "The only problem remaining is that you end up in hangouts..." This is not true, you end up in hangouts only if the user choose it as the default sms app. In order to validate your solution, I suggest that you would choose another app to be the default sms app and test your solution again (for example try contact+, I'm sure that there are others too)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, the problem is not that the user ends up in Hangouts (if it is configured as the default SMS client), but that you need to press back multiple times to get back.  I consider this a bug in Hangouts.

Comment: The back thing is since the hangouts is written with the new navigation guidelines, that if you ask me, only people who read the guideline can follow it. For the common user, I'm sure it was better with the old guidelines. What you call a bug they call a feature (I agree with you)

Comment: is startActivity called twice on KITKAT with this sample?

Comment: Thanks for the bug report, fixed.

Comment: The above code does not work for Nexus 5 with Lollipop - Hangouts opens up on the contact but no pre-populated text. Anyone stumbled upon a solution?

Comment: @nitzanj : yup facing the same issue. Nexus 5 Lollipop Hangouts app basically doesn't take in the sms body text

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin following code works:

```
val defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(activity)  
            val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            sendIntent.type = "text/plain"
            sendIntent.putExtra("address", "sms:"+contactNumber)
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.share_msg_body))
            Timber.e("defaultSmsPackageName: "+defaultSmsPackageName)
            if (defaultSmsPackageName != null){ //Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose any app that support this intent.
                sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName)
                activity!!.startActivity(sendIntent)
            }
```