# Send SMS without user interface in android 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I'm trying to send SMS without user interface with SMSManager . thats ok on android 4.1.2 and below but it's not working in Android 4.4.2.

This is my code :

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> msgStringArray = sms.divideMessage(message);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, msgStringArray, null,null);
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: not working means?????

Comment: yup . that's ok on android 4.1.2 and below but not working on android 4.4.2

Comment: where are you testing???

Comment: am testing on Nexus 5 with android 4.4.2

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20079048/3168859)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your app cannot send an SMS because of changes in Android 4.4.  Outlined at https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#SMS you can see the changes.

> **SMS Provider** The Telephony content provider (the "SMS Provider")
>   allows apps to read and write SMS and MMS messages on the device. It
>   includes tables for SMS and MMS messages received, drafted, sent,
>   pending, and more.
>
> Beginning with Android 4.4, the system settings allow users to select
>   a "default SMS app." **Once selected, only the default SMS app is able
>   to write to the SMS Provider** and only the default SMS app receives the
>   SMS_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast when the user receives an SMS or the
>   WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast when the user receives an MMS. The
>   default SMS app is responsible for writing details to the SMS Provider
>   when it receives or sends a new message.
>
> Other apps that are not selected as the default SMS app can only read
>   the SMS Provider, but may also be notified when a new SMS arrives by
>   listening for the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast, which is a
>   non-abortable broadcast that may be delivered to multiple apps. This
>   broadcast is intended for apps that---while not selected as the
>   default SMS app---need to read special incoming messages such as to
>   perform phone number verification.
>
> For more information, read the blog post, Getting Your SMS Apps Ready
>   for KitKat.