# How to set my application as default to receive SMS

Tags: android, sms, message, google-hangouts

i'm developing an application to send and receive SMS. I want to add the option to set my application as default like Hangout of Google:

[image]

Do you have an ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please have a look at the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079047/android-kitkat-4-4-hangouts-cannot-handle-sending-sms-intent http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html Hope these links will help you what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How to set your app as default messaging app?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME);
```

How to check if your app is default messaging app?

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static boolean isDefaultSmsApp(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageName().equals(Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context));
}
```

From the preference activity add OnPreferenceClickListener and add the following code inside it which first check if it is already a default messaging app, then opens a screen where the user can change it else set the current app as the default messaging app.
[image: Confirmation screen user will get]

```
 if (isDefaultSmsApp(getActivity())) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                    } else {
                    final String packageName = getActivity().getPackageName();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                        intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    }
```

Comment: not working :(. i used ur code in my MainActivity onCreate()

Comment: I'd like to run above code in library, but it's not working, can you please help me?

Comment: @KrzysztofHuminski can you provide some details on problem?

Comment: http://pulse7.net/android/android-delete-sms-message-from-inbox-in-android/ I'm following this tutorial in my project, but it's not working.

Comment: I implemented the listeners and receivers in the library and tried to run it via using the above code, but it does not show the confirmation dialog.

Comment: I got it working, I was missing SendSms activity and it's working now.