# Android. Set phone number when sending message by hangout

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, google-hangouts

I want to set phone number when I send message by hangout.

When I use sms, it can be done as below.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
sendIntent.putExtra("adress", phoneNumber);
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But I don't know how set phone number or target by phone number in hangout..
Here is my current code using hangout.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) //At least KitKat
    {
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null)
        {
            sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
        context.startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
```

EDITED..!

I found solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079047/android-kitkat-4-4-hangouts-cannot-handle-sending-sms-intent).
See the @Roberto B.'s solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code recently, and it seems to work as your require:

```
public static void sendSMS(Activity activity, String message, String phoneNumber){

        Intent smsIntent;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            //Ensures only SMS apps respond
            smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber));

            //No resolvable activity
            if (smsIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) == null) {
                return;
            }

        }else{
            //Old way of accessing sms activity
            smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
            smsIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
        }
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
        activity.startActivity(smsIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment!! I tested your code. But in kitkat, smsIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) returns null.